# Need help randomizing numbers based on user input

Tags: java

```
    public class numberCube {

    public static int size;
    public static int tosses;
    public static int random;
    public static int value;
    public static int values;


    public static void cubeSize(){
```

//   Gets the range of numbers that are allowed to be randomized

```
String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                ("How many numbers do you want on your cube?");

        int size = Integer.parseInt(x);

    }
    public static void numTosses(){
```

// Gets the amount of times that a randomizer will loop

```
 String y = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                ("How many times do you want to toss the dice?");

        int tosses = Integer.parseInt(y);

    }

    public static void randomizer(){
```

// creates the random numbers. Heres where the problem is. I need to be able //to allow the user to specify the range of numbers and how many times it will //be randomized 
  For example, for cubeSize() I could enter 3, and for numTosses() I could enter 5. A possible output would be: 1,1,3,2,3

```
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: uh.. what was the question? i wonder what `int value = 16 + random.nextInt(5);` does do, and what do you expect it do.. as far as i know it will result in `16 + some random number from 0 to 4`.. so, it'll gave numbers around 16 to 20..

Comment: My bad, that code was copied from somewhere on google. The entire randomizer() method can be changed however it would best work, since i have no clue where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You're duplicating the initialization of variables `(ex: size,tosses,etc)` here.

If want to manipulate a property of a specific class you need to use `this` keyword. So,

`int size = Integer.parseInt(x);` becomes `this.size = Integer.parseInt(x);`

`int tosses = Integer.parseInt(y);` becomes `this.tosses = Integer.parseInt(y);`

`etc..`

Then in your `randomizer()` method you could try something like :

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i <= this.tosses; i++) {
    int value = 1 + random.nextInt(this.size);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: np!If it was helpful don't forget to accept it as it may be useful for someone else in future!  Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < numTosses; ++i) {
    int rand = 1 + r.nextInt(cubeSize);
    // use rand, which will be an integer from 1 to cubeSize (inclusive)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, but it doesn't seem to be outputting anything when i use the variables instead of actual numbers.